# "Stand-alone" serial monitor

Tags: serial, ide

I usually use [Platformio](http://platformio.org) as IDE for my Arduino projects. I like it as an editor, but I don't like its serial monitor feature. So I often open the Arduino IDE in background to use its serial monitor, but this has some drawbacks (including a significant increase in my computer's CPU usage and battery consumption).

Is there an Arduino-compatible serial monitor application that just works as a serial monitor (and not also as an IDE)? I'm most interested in a MacOS application, but if you know a Windows one please tell me as well.

Comment: putty ... http://www.putty.org/ ...

Comment: I regularly use GNU screen. For example `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200` where `/dev/ttyUSB0` is the serial port of the Arduino, and 115200 is the baud rate.
What's wrong with the PlatformIO serial monitor, by the way?

Comment: you can use any serial terminal, search for them. putty is pretty good. aside: do you get constant CPU usage from the arduino program as well? (thought it was just me...)

Comment: You can use almost anything; but the catch with using something not integrated is that it may not automatically get out of the way when you try to upload code.

Comment: @tttapa thanks. Is there also some kind of gnu serial port scanner? — the biggest issue (for me) is the fact that I can’t copy the output (I don’t know if it’s an issue of PlatformIO, Atom or something on my computer... but as I select one serial monitor word all the text in the window get selected); a secondary problem is that putting data in is quite tricky (compared to the Arduino ide serial monitor)

Comment: @dandavis sorry, what do you mean by “do you get constant CPU usage from the arduino program as well?”

Comment: Note also that terminal emulators (putty, GNU screen, ...) are way more capable than the Arduino serial monitor, as they let you use [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to control the cursor, set colors, etc. C.f. the bar display at the top left of [this screenshot](https://www.logre.eu/mediawiki/images/0/0d/ADC-Arduino-console.png).

Comment: sometimes the IDE pegs my CPU at 25% even idle (the OS blames java), was wondering if that same nastyness was what caused the battery consumption you mentioned...

Comment: @noearchimede of course you can copy from the terminal. It just uses a different short cut. On Linux, this is `CTRL+SHIFT+C` instead of `CTRL+C` (`CTRL+C` sends a break), not sure what the Mac equivalent is.

Comment: @dandavis yes, that happens quite often and it probably is the most important battery consumption cause

Comment: @dandavis *do you get constant CPU usage from the arduino program as well?* - I found a while ago that under certain circumstances (failed upload was one I think) that the IDE went to using 100% CPU. The only reason it took a while to notice was that I have a 4-core CPU and the other CPUs kept running. I think it wasn't the IDE per se, but a process running `avrdude` that was looping. After 4 failed uploads my PC got a bit sluggish. :)

Comment: @NickGammon: yup, that's it. if i have several sketches open, sometimes I can close 1+ of them (not all) and the 100% usage goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [CoolTerm](http://freeware.the-meiers.org/), which is available for Mac, Windows and Linux. It is a great serial app, and you can have several windows open at the same, for each serial pipe you may be using (Bluetooth, Arduino Serial, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Consider building your own monitor in Python. This gives you flexibility since Python is cross platform and you can tailor the monitor to your needs.

1. Install [Python](https://www.python.org).
2. Install [pySerial](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/) (`pip install pyserial`).
3. Write a Python script to read and/or write to the Arduino across the serial port. There are some great examples out there such as [this example](https://www.thepoorengineer.com/en/arduino-python-plot/) and other [Stack Overflow answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074914/python-to-arduino-serial-read-write)

Answer (score 3):

On macOS, you can use the built-in `screen` command, e.g.:

```
screen /dev/cu.usbmodem14201 9600
```

To exit, <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

There's a list of serial port sniffers here, if you want to view raw data

[softwarerecs.stackexchange serial-port-logging](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7636/serial-port-logging/7639#7639)

And a list here of programs which plot graphs from serial data:

[softwarerecs.stackexchange serial-data-plotting-programs](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1180/serial-data-plotting-programs)